# Script help for interacting between HTML and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-mobile

Looking for some guidance on script that will pass the JSON file information to the HTML. The HTML is going to be a single page but using jQuery Mobile to create the multiple page effect. On the first page I'm looking to just display the names of each person and then when you click on the person for the information for that person to be displayed on the second page. I'm new to JSON just can't seem to wrap my head around to manage this script.

HTML File:

```
<!--first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="info-page">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Contacts</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" id="prof-list">
      <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b" role="heading">Names</li>
      <!-- List of all names from the JSON file listed here -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!--second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="details-page">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Go back</a>
    <h1>Information</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="list-view">
    <!-- Information for person who was clicked on show here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

JSON File:
(There is more people on the actual file)

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "age": 31,
    "name": "Alex Jones",
    "email": "alexjones@gmail.com",
    "phone": "+1 (845) 575-2978"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "age": 31,
    "name": "Alice Hollow",
    "email": "alicehollow@gmail.com",
    "phone": "+1 (829) 454-3806"
},
```

Comment: How are you accessing the JSON file?

Comment: Im new to JSON so im not really sure the best method. currently just have the file being called like a js <script src="json/contacts.json"></script> I've seen mthods of having the JSON data as a variable in a js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming that you already have the JSON as an array of objects, because I couldn't tell from your partial JSON what format it's in. Here it is in <kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZqPOzdmaqPwzvxbBW4JU?p=preview)</kbd>

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#page2">Page Two</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#page3">Page Three</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#page4">Page Four</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" id="prof-list">
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b" role="heading">Names</li>
        <!-- List of all names from the JSON file listed here -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
  </div>


  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Go back</a>
      <h1>Information</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <td id="dataName">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Age</th>
          <td id="dataAge">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Email</th>
          <td id="dataEmail">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <td id="dataPhone">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page Three</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      Content
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page Four</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      Content
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var contacts = [{
      "id": 0,
      "age": 31,
      "name": "Alex Jones",
      "email": "alexjones@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+1 (845) 575-2978"
    }, {
      "id": 1,
      "age": 31,
      "name": "Alice Hollow",
      "email": "alicehollow@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+1 (829) 454-3806"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "age": 99999,
      "name": "Lazerus",
      "email": "What is this EE-mall you speak of?",
      "phone": "Fown? I know not of this person."
    }];

    var listName = document.getElementById("prof-list");


    function displayNames(arr) {
      var out = "";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<li><a href="' + arr[i].name + '" id="' + arr[i].id + '">' + arr[i].name + '</a></li>';
      }
      listName.innerHTML = out;
      listName.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
          var ID = parseInt(e.target.id, 10);
          document.getElementById('dataName').innerHTML = arr[ID].name;
          document.getElementById('dataAge').innerHTML = arr[ID].age;
          document.getElementById('dataEmail').innerHTML = arr[ID].email;
          document.getElementById('dataPhone').innerHTML = arr[ID].phone;
        }
      }, false);

    }

    displayNames(contacts);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is kind of what I'm looking for. Is there away to create the names as a list item instead of just a href.
Secondly is there away of just having one page where when you click on a name it just adds the information to the second page of the person clicked instead of creating multiple pages as i have about 50-60 people.

Comment: Yep: `out += '<li><a href="' + arr[i].name + '" id="' + arr[i].id + '">' + arr[i].name + '</a></li>';` and concerning the second query, do you mean that you'd like each click to be an accumulative result on the second page? (Ex. You clicked Mary, John, Doug, and Mary again (on accident), then as a result on the second page is the info for: Mary, John, and Doug)

Comment: I'd like it so that you click Mary it shows the info for just Mary on the second page then the go back button brings you back to the main page( i have that back button working) then you pick someone else on the list and rinse and repeat for anyone else but rewriting the information on the second page for the person that was clicked on

Comment: I updated the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZqPOzdmaqPwzvxbBW4JU?p=preview) with an additional contact that is way different than the first 2 contacts. The first 2 contacts do look very similar, or have you tried the examples yet?

Comment: I just changed the links to links nested in a list item and jQM made it into a nice directory. The Snippet is updated as well.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the question, I forgot how appealing and convenient jQM is.